# Need random sample: Weibull distribution with specific inter-arrival times

Tags: r, statistics, weibull

I am using `R`, and would like to generate a number of observations using `rweibull(n, shape, scale = 1)`.

I have the arrival rate (i.e. 1/interarrival time), but I do not know how to use it in `rweibull` function.

Comment: This isn't really a question about R, this is a stats question about how to use the weibull distribution. You should try asking this over at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You need to work out what arrival rate corresponds to; it's probably the scale (or 1/scale).

Answer (score 2):

The scale parameter is what you need to be working with and the shape parameter is what needs to be set to 1 to create an exponential distribution. The scale parameter is 1/rate:

```
 interT = 8
 plot( density(rexp(100, rate=1/interT)) )
 with( density(rweibull(100, scale=interT, shape=1)), 
   lines(x,y, col="red"))
```

(But if you are using the survival package you need to be aware that the parameters are different.)

Comment: Thanks guys. What I am trying to do is generating random numbers as a arrival time of web traffic, this follow Wiebull. I know the arrival rate for web traffic/s.  Dwin for scale=1/rate. do you mean by rate is the inter-arrival time or the arrival rate? I only have the arrival rate so can I say scale=1/arrival rate? So the function works like this: rweibull(n, shape=1, scale = 1/arrival rate)?

Comment: What I meant was that the `rweibull` 'scale' parameter was equivalent to an `rexp` 1/'rate' parameter, in the case where the rweibull:shape = 1. My example used an "inter-arrival time" of 8 (in unspecified units) and was intended to demonstrate (modulo random draws) that equivalence.